# ESC key doesn`t work when I enter 'vi .bash_profile'

Tags: linux, centos, vmware, bash

[image]

As I said on title, ESC key does not work when I enter to 'vi .bash_profile' and I have to use forced termination. I searched other question already and I tried press 'Ctrl+[' but it was not working also. Does anybody know how to escape from 'vi .bash_profile' after editing?

Comment: There are [many ways to avoid the ESC key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key), including your own custom mapping.

Comment: Did you try ESC twice?

Answer (score 1):

> ESC key does not work when I enter to 'vi .bash_profile' and I have to
>   use forced termination.

`vi` is not terminated by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. To exit from `vi`, there are a number of ways:

- `:q`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> - don't write changes
- `:x`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> - write any changes
- …